# Merging two object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I having the following code to merge the two objects

**Code:**

```
var goals = {1:"first",2:"second"};
var pages = {1:"page1",2:"page2"};

var result = {};

for(var goal in goals){
  for(var page in pages){
       if(page.hasOwnProperty(goal)){
         result[goal] = {"goal":goals[goal],"page":pages[page]};
      }
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

**Expected result:**

```
result = {1:{"goal":"first","page":"page1"},2:{"goal":"second","page":"page2"}};
```

code is working fine and getting the expected output.

Any suggestion to change it or it is better to go with this.

**Improved code**

```
    var result = {};

    for(var goal in goals){
     if(pages.hasOwnProperty(goal)){
        result[goal] = {"goal":goals[goal],"page":pages[goal]};
      }
    }
```

Comment: @lukas.pukenis Edited the code.is it correct now?

Comment: if pages has more properties then it will not show up in your output. Will  this scenario happen?

Comment: thanks all for answering

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is O(m*n). The following is of O(m+n):

```
var goals = {1:"first",2:"second"};
var pages = {1:"page1",2:"page2"};

var result = {};
for(var x in goals){
if(!result[x])result[x] = {};
result[x].goals = goals[x];
}
for(var x in pages){
if(!result[x])result[x] = {};
result[x]. page = pages[x];
}
```

Comment: Could be more efficient & complete still: while looping over one object, check if those keys exist in the second. Delete the property if it does, after adding it to the result, of course (cf my answer). You're also not filtering (`hasOwnProperty`) the loop. It's redundant 9/10 cases, true, but you never know how the OP is going to use your code

Answer (score 1):

With Underscore.js you get a nice and simple one-liner:

```
var result = _.extend(goals, pages);
```

Comment: I highly recommend underscore as well

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `obj.hasOwnProperty()`.

When you do `for x in y` it provides you all the properties and methods of an object.

`obj.hasOwnProperty()` tells you if a property is a direct property on the object or in it's prototype(if returns false).

Your extend function should look like this:

```
function extend(src, dst){
    for(var key in dst)
        if(dst.hasOwnProperty(key))
            src[key] = dst[key];
    return src;
```